# EditText with android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen" wont work with OnKeyListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText that displays an Error message/validation on done button press using the setOnKeyListener.

This has been working well in portrait on my Nexus 5, however when in landscape it had full screen EditBox. I press done, and only once I close the keyboard is the error visible.

So I added android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
and android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

both of these stop the fullscreen input, but also stop the OnKeyListener

TextWatchers still works, but this is no good for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnKeyListener isn't a reliable way to work with a software keyboard anyway.  It will work with some keyboards some of the time, but its meant for hardware keys (including hardware keyboards), not for software keyboards which generally do not send hardware events.  You need to use TextWatchers to work reliably with an onscreen keyboard.

Comment: OK, ive not had a problem before. how can I use them to detect enter/done key?

Comment: For the done key, use setOnEditorActionListener and it should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Add *actionGo* flag to imeOptions.

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionGo"
```